# Friends List Pagination

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have got a feature on  my website called 'View friends' that displays a hidden div containing a users friends.  The only problem so far is I would like it so that it would show 7 members on each row for 3 rows so a total of 21 members on each page.  I know I will have to round up NumOfMembers/21 giving me the pages needed.  I just need some advice in how I should set up the pagination from when thee SQL query gets the total amount of friends.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL-query should use the `limit` and `offset` parameters for pagination, depending on the page *n* you are on, like this:

```
SELECT .... LIMIT 21 OFFSET n*21
```

When handling the results, simply use the *modulo* operator for determining the lines and rows your current result has to be put in:

```
// where $i is the result number
$row = $i % 7;
$line = $i % 3;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I now understand the concept thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

First you can load everything from the php in one query and put all users in an array(content), and just display in pages!

```
content = [];
max = 21;

function handlePaginationClick(page, pagination_container) {

    $('#MyContentArea').empty();
    for(var i=0;i<max;i++) {
        if(null!=content[(page*max)+i]) $('#MyContentArea').append(content[(page*max)+i]);
    }
    return false;
}
$("#News-Pagination").pagination(content.length, {
        items_per_page:max,
        callback:handlePaginationClick
});
```

you can use Jquery Pagination: https://github.com/gbirke/jquery_pagination#readme
 for that.

Another approach is still using jquery pagination, but not load everything at once! then you  must have same ajax call in the method 'handlePaginationClick' to pull all page information.

Comment: I'm guessing just doing one query at the start to get all the friends and using the JQuery for pagination would be more efficient than making an ajax request every time the next page is selected right?

Comment: The plugin I have used is described in http://plugins.jquery.com/project/combogrid

Comment: I mean! if you dont have 5000 users should be ok! also much easier solution! just copy my code, change same a bit ! and you are ready to go!